# Unequal length between strings after writing to a file - using same delimiter (tab)

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a short procedure in PL/SQL which uses UTL_FILE package to create and then write to a .txt file.
Tab is saved in its own variable (v_delimiter), declared as varchar2(5), with a value of chr(9).
The header is saved as a string, concatenated with the v_delimiter and then written to a file.
After that, the rest of the data from an explicit cursor is also written to a file, line by line.
In the end, when I open the txt file, there are unequal widths between some of the strings which make up a header. There are also unequal widths between some of the data from the cursor inside a final .txt file and I guess that shouldn't be since I am using one and the same delimiter (tab) to create a header and to create a string from a cursor.

I am using UTL_FILE.put_line_nchar function to write a Unicode line to a file.
I tried without declaring a delimiter as a variable, using literally chr(9) when concatenating and it is always the same result.
I am out of ideas why is this happening in the final txt file.

```
 v_file_handle     UTL_FILE.file_type ;
 v_output_path   VARCHAR2 (100) := '/Path/to/File' ;
 v_file_header   VARCHAR2 (32767) ;
 v_delimiter     VARCHAR2 (5) := chr(9) ;

v_file_handle := UTL_FILE.fopen_nchar (v_output_path,'string_1' || TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'dd_mm_yyyy') || '.txt','w', 32767); -- opening 

v_file_header :='claimFileIdentifier'|| v_delimiter || 'claimFileOpenedDate'
|| v_delimiter|| 'claimStatus'|| v_delimiter|| 'claimStatusDate'|| v_delimiter|| 'incidentDateTime'|| v_delimiter|| 'incidentPlace'|| v_delimiter|| 'calculationType' ... -- header 

 UTL_FILE.put_line_nchar ( v_file_handle, v_file_header ) ; --writing header to a file 

 FOR rec IN cursor_candidates --iterating over a cursor 
   
   LOOP

      UTL_FILE.put_line_nchar (
         v_file_handle,
            rec.claimFileIdentifier
         || v_delimiter
         || rec.claimFileOpenedDate
         || v_delimiter
         || rec.claimStatus
         || v_delimiter
         || rec.claimStatusDate
         || v_delimiter
         || rec.incidentDateTime
         || v_delimiter
         || rec.incidentPlace
         || v_delimiter ... ) ; -- writing cursor rows to a file 

  END LOOP ; 

  UTL_FILE.fclose ( v_file_handle );
```

[Final txt file and unequal width between certain strings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkX0r.png)

Comment: You have not shared any code with us; if we do not know what you are doing it is impossible for us to give an answer (beyond blindly guessing). Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data; **YOUR** code (or a minimal example of your code); the output for that sample data; and the expected output for that sample data.

Comment: I thought I explained the situation well enough, but it seems I didn't. Here, I've added a piece of code that I think is most relevant to my problem. The whole procedure is much bigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This relating to the functionality of the client application that you use to open the output tab-separated values (TSV) file.

If I have the data:

```
longtitle   longtitle2  longtitle3
a   b   c
1234567890  123456789010234545  1234567788
```

and I open it in a basic text editor (such as Notepad) then the output is:

[image: Notepad formatted output]

And the columns are unequal across the rows.

However, if I display the same data in an editor that supports TSV files (such as Notepad++) then it displays the same output with equal widths for the columns across the rows:

[image: Notepad++ formatted output]

Importing the data into a spreadsheet application (such as Excel or OpenOffice), then the TSV is separated into cells and the output is:

[image: Excel formatted output]

And, again, the information is split into columns.

---

Do not change how you are outputting the file; instead, find a better way of viewing the output file with an application that supports formatting tab-separated values.

Answer (score 1):

That's kind of *expected*, in my opinion. Values *are* separated by the TAB character, but it doesn't mean that output will look "nice" when you look at it as a text file.

For example, following values are separated by TAB, but they look *ugly*:

```
a   b   c
Littlefoot  Scott   Tiger
```

If you e.g. imported that file into Excel and set TAB as column separator, every value would be in its own column and output would look *pretty*.

If you wanted text file to look nice as well, you'll have to use a different approach, e.g. `LPAD` numeric values (IDs, salaries, ...), `RPAD` textual strings (names, addresses, ...), possibly `SUBSTR` (to cut long values short).

Comment: That's the thing, it doesn't have to look nice, I am not after that. The widths vary and they shouldn't since only one delimiter is used. Do you want to say that even though it doesn't look equally separated, everything is actually tab separated, but to an eye it isn't ?

Comment: Exactly. If you wanted to use TAB as delimiter and see the result look "nice", you'd have to use variable number of TABs because some values are short, while others are long (see example I posted; "a" is much shorter than "Littlefoot" so you'd need **4** TABs after "a" to match only 1 TAB after "Littlefoot" so that the 2nd value would be properly adjusted. But, if you opened such a file in Excel, you'd get *garbage*.